# Why can't I override the container padding variable in BootstrapVue?

Tags: bootstrap-4, themes, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a theme for BootstrapVue 2.0 (which uses Bootstrap 4.3) following the [VueBootstrap theming guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/). I have a `theme.scss` file which has my overrides at the beginning and imports the base styles at the end. I am trying to override the default container horizontal padding but it doesn't seem to work.

**theme.scss**

```
$container-padding-x: 30px !default;

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

The padding on the left and right side of the container remains at the default `15px`.

Further, if I try overriding the gutter width, it works and the change even adjusts the container padding, since it the container padding is half the gutter width.

```
$grid-gutter-width: 60px !default;
```

Why is there a discrepancy with variable overrides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$container-padding-x` is not a variable in Bootstrap v4.3.x (but is in the yet to be released v5.x)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

The control of grid padding is controlled by `$grid-gutter-width`, which applied to rows (negative margin of `$grid-gutter-width / 2`), and padding of columns (`$grid-gutter-width / 2`)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_grid-framework.scss

`containers` also get an x-padding of `$grid-gutter-width / 2`

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_grid.scss

Comment: Strange since it's available in Bootstrap 4's master branch https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L216

Comment: master branch is now for version 5 of Bootstrap (not v4)